# Auto-scrollable panel

Tags: wpf, scrollviewer

I have an items control which allows user to drag and re-size items within it. Items may be dragged out of the viewable area and in such a case I'd like to show respective scroll bars.

Here's the portion of xaml

```
<ControlTemplate x:Key="ItemsControlTemplate" TargetType ="ItemsControl">
    <ScrollViewer HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
       <ItemsPresenter />
    </ScrollViewer>
</ControlTemplate>

<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Models}"                                              
              Margin="10,10,10,10"
              Grid.Row="1"
              VerticalContentAlignment="Stretch"
              HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch"   
              Template="{StaticResource ItemsControlTemplate}">                   
    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>                            
            <Canvas  ClipToBounds="True"
                     SnapsToDevicePixels="True"/>                                             
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <ContentControl  Height="400" Width="600"   
                             Canvas.Left="50" Canvas.Top="150"
                             Template="{StaticResource DesignerItemTemplate}"
                             Margin="10,10,10,10">
                <Views:ChartView />
            </ContentControl>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

The xaml shows the bars but when an item is dragged out of view the bars are not enabled.

Answer (score 0):

From [Canvas Class Remarks](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.canvas.aspx):

> Canvas is the only panel element that has no inherent layout
>   characteristics. A Canvas has default Height and Width properties of
>   zero, unless it is the child of an element that automatically sizes
>   its child elements. Child elements of a Canvas are never resized, they
>   are just positioned at their designated coordinates. This provides
>   flexibility for situations in which inherent sizing constraints or
>   alignment are not needed or wanted. For cases in which you want child
>   content to be automatically resized and aligned, it is usually best to
>   use a Grid element.

That's why bars are never shown.

Comment: Thanks for the response.I've figured already how to display them when needed